# jQuery return appended element

Tags: jquery, append, return

Good morning, I have this code that should categorize numbers into odd and even categories. It does so by going through numbers and creating a new category when necessary. Right after a new category is created it is appended with a new row containing a number. The problem is that it tends to skip the first element of the new category (i.e 1 and 2 are not included in the corresponding categories).

I can solve this by searching for a category again(commented out code(jsfiddle l:12)), but I would like to get the newly created category element from addNewCategory function, is that possible?

```
var content = $('#content');

// add one row to the category
var addRow = function (number) {
    var categoryId = (number % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'),
        $category = content.find('#category_' + categoryId)
    ;

    // category exists?
    if(!$category.length) {
        $category = addNewCategory (number);
        //$category = content.find('#category_' + categoryId);
    }

    // prepare new row
    var row = '<div class="row">' + number + '</div>';
    $category.append(row);
};

    // add new category
var addNewCategory = function(number) {
    var categoryId = (number % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'),
        category = '<div class="category" id="category_' + categoryId + '">' + categoryId + '</div>';

    content.append(category);
    return $(category);
};

// start
for(var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    addRow(i);
}
```

jsfiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdhTa/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [.appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)

```
var addNewCategory = function(number) {
    var categoryId = (number % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'),
        category = '<div class="category" id="category_' + categoryId + '">' + categoryId + '</div>';

    return $(category).appendTo(content)
};
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you. But why would it not work with `append`?

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your Fiddle to that code http://jsfiddle.net/rdhTa/1/ :

```
var content = $('#content');

// add one row to the category
var addRow = function (number) {
    var categoryId = (number % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd');
    var category = content.find('#category_' + categoryId) ;

    // category exists?
    if(category.length == 0) {
        addNewCategory (number);
        category = content.find('#category_' + categoryId);
    }

    // prepare new row
    var row = '<div class="row">' + number + '</div>';
    category.append(row);
};

    // add new category
    var addNewCategory = function(number) {
    var categoryId = (number % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'),
    category = '<div class="category" id="category_' + categoryId + '">' + categoryId + '</div>';

    content.append(category);
    return;
};

// start
for(var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    addRow(i);
}
```